# Вытаскивание текстур из игр на LibGDX

Tags: java, android, c++, opengl, libgdx

**Здравствуйте, хотел бы узнать, как вытащить текстуры**

Хочу извлечь текстуры из игры Sara Is Missing. Игра работает на фреймворке LibGDX, вышло так, что текстуры сохранены в формате .texture, и это не тот, что .dds. Тут иная ситуация, вытащить никак не получается. Посмотрев исходники я понял, что LibGDX перекодирует изображения в формат .texture при компиляции. Как я могу сделать обратные действия?

Пример файла текстуры: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16eCVVKxiZM4J-Z16fZjE4dBgpJZZWBBQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: print screen?))

Comment: Не сработает, ибо в игре существует куча визуальных глитч эффектов, и часто картинки накладываются друг на друга.

Comment: приложите к вопросу бинарь текстуры - попробую

Comment: @StrangerintheQ добавил

Comment: Что там? Нашел способ?

Comment: Я кажись нашел библиотеку, которая закодировала эти файлы. Sengine - кастомная библиотека, используемая в Sara is Missing. Скидываю исходник библиотеки: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZgxDnrIHWQYrskHkqjjAbS9BOpyRq8jt/view?usp=sharing